# Included setup.py in bdist generated library

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I am trying to generate a simple Python library using the following command:

```
> python setup.py bdist_dumb
```

So it will generate a tar.gz file with the contents specified in the setup.py script.

Once it is generated, I try to install ot using pip install command, but I am getting an error referring to the missing file setup.py.

I have specified to include such file in a MANIFEST.in file. But when I attempt to build the file, it is not included in my package.

As a reference I am checking pyspark package, but I can't find the place where the setup.py file is specified to be included.

Can anyone give me a hint for including this file in order to install the tar.gz library?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a wrong question for a wrong problem. You don't need to include `setup.py` because you don't need to build `bdist_dumb`. [Dumb distributions](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html) cannot be installed with `pip`.

If you want a pip-installable distribution build a source distribution, an egg or a wheel:

```
python setup.py sdist
python setup.py bdist_egg

pip install wheel
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```